# the product $(X_1, T_1)\times\ldots\times(X_n,T_n)$ is locally compact, then each $(X_i, T_i)$ is locally compact.

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Prove that the product $(X_1, T_1)\times\ldots\times(X_n, T_n)$ is locally compact, then each $(X_i, T_i)$ is locally compact.

My proof: Let $p=\langle x_1,\ldots,x_n\rangle$ be in the product.

Since the product is locally compact, there exists a compact neighborhood $K_1\times\ldots\times K_n$ of $p$. Since $K_1\times\ldots\times K_n$ is compact, each factor $K_i$ is compact.

There is an open set $U_1\times\ldots\times U_n$ in the product such that $p$ is in $U_1\times\ldots\times U_n$ which is the subset of $K_1\times\ldots\times K_n$. So, each $U_i$ is open in $X_i$. For each $x_i$ of a compact neighborhood $K_i$, there exists an open set $U_i$ for $i=1,2,\ldots,n$ such that $x_i$ is in $U_i$ which is the subset of $K_i$. Therefore each $(X_i,T_i)$ is locally compact. Is it ok?

Comment: Didn't you ask the same question before? Compose the product with the (continuous) projection onto the i-th space, and use that continuous sends compact to compact.

Comment: no. they are not the same

Comment: what is wrong with my proof?

Comment: My bad, this is local compactness. Sorry.

Comment: is my proof ok?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to show. Is it that $U_1 \times U_2 \times...\times U_n$ contains the compact neighborhood $K_1 \times K_2 \times ...\times K_n$? If so, it looks correct to me. There are slightly-different definitions ( not all equivalent, of course) of local compactness.

Comment: So, what's your definition of local compactness?

Comment: locally compact:if each point in a set X has at least one neighborhood which is compact.

Comment: O.K, then it's fine; the neighborhood: $K_1\times K_2 \times ...\times K_n$ is a compact neighborhood of $p=(x_1,..,x_n)$.

Comment: It’s not quite right: how do you know that $p$ has a compact nbhd **of the form** $K_1\times\ldots\times K_n$?

Comment: Oh, so we don't really know if  K1×K2×...×Kn is a compact nbhd of p even though we know that (X1,T1)×…×(Xn,Tn) is locally compact?

Comment: @Brian M. Scott: well, if $x_i \subset K_i$ , with $K_i$ compact , and $p=(x_1,x_2,..,x_n)$ , isn't $K_1 \times K_2 \times....\times K_n$ a compact ( product neighborhood) of $p$?

Comment: @user99680: Yes, a product of that form is compact, but there are compact sets in $X_1\times\ldots\times X_n$ that aren’t of that form. All you know is that $p$ has a compact nbhd; you **don’t** know (until you prove it, as I did) that $p$ has a compact **product** nbhd.

Answer (score 1):

You have most of the pieces, but not quite all of them. Also, you could organize the argument a little better: to show that one of the factor spaces $X_k$ is locally compact, you should start with an arbitrary point of $X_k$ and show that it has a compact nbhd.

Let $X=X_1\times\ldots\times X_n$. Fix $k\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$; you want to show that $X_k$ is locally compact, so let $x_k\in X_k$. For each $i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}\setminus\{k\}$ let $x_i\in X_i$, and let $p=\langle x_1,\ldots,x_n\rangle$. The product space is locally compact, so $p$ has a compact nbhd $K$. Since $K$ **is** a nbhd of $p$, there are open sets $U_i\in T_i$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$ such that $p\in U_1\times\ldots\times U_n\subseteq K$. For $i=1,\ldots,n$ let $K_i=\operatorname{cl}_{X_i}U_i$; then

$$K_1\times\ldots\times K_n=\operatorname{cl}_X(U_1\times\ldots\times U_n)\subseteq K\;.$$

Thus, $K_1\times\ldots\times K_n$ is a compact nbhd of $p$, and it follows that $K_k$ is compact. But $x_k\in U_k\subseteq K_k$, wher

Comment: Compact subsets are not necessarily closed if the space is not Hausdorff, so you could have $U \subseteq K$ but $\mathrm{cl}(U) \not \subseteq K$

Comment: @Ramiro: I'm well aware that compact sets need not be closed if the space is not Hausdorff. Since the OP didn't specify a definition of local compactness, I chose to assume the condition that makes them all equivalent, which is often taken to be part of the definition of local compactness anyway.

Answer (score 1):

There are competing definitions of local compactness. One of them means that the space has arbitrary small compact neighborhoods. The other one means that the space is Hausdorff and each point has a compact neighborhood. The second one implies the first one.

No matter which one you are using, if the product has the property, then each factor has it. This can be seen by noting that the projection maps are open and continuous. And if $f:X\to Y$ is a continuous open surjection, $y\in Y$ is a point and $x\in X$ such that $f(x)=y$, then any compact neighborhood $K$ of $x$ maps to a neighborhood $f(K)$ of $y$ since $f$ is open and this $f(K)$ is compact since $f$ is continuous. If you want $f(K)$ to be contained in some given neighborhood $V$, just choose $K$ small enough so it is in $f^{-1}(V)$.

Also note that each factor is Hausdorff if the product is. So the statement is true for both definitions.